# Cannot get selenium webdriver Java script to run

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Hi I'm new to webdriver I'm trying to get a script to run. When I run the script it opens the browser and enters the log in details but the @Test part does not. I've tried using css locator x path etc. but nothing I've tried works. Has anyone any ideas or advice that could help?

```
package firsttestngpackage;    

    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class FirstTestNGFile {
        public String baseUrl = "http://zzzz";
        public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        @BeforeTest
        public void login() {
            driver.get(baseUrl);
            WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("z_username"));
            id.sendKeys("todd");
            WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("z_password"));
            pass.sendKeys("todd");
            WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("login"));
            button.submit();
        }

        @Test
        public void createSub() {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Customers")).click();
        }

        @AfterTest
        public void terminateBrowser() {
            driver.quit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your test method is missing closing `}`. I edited the code. Try with including `}`

Comment: Still having issues it logs in and closes but doesn't click the customers link.

Comment: Please provide html and exception

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
<h2 class="accessibility">Navigation</h2>
<ul id="primary-nav" class="menuList">
<li class="pad"/>
<li>
<li>
<li class="menubar">
<li class="menubar">
<li class="menubar">
<li class="menubar">
<li class="menubar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Polciy" class="current">Policy</a>
<ul>
<li class="menubar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="SPL">SPL</a>
<ul>
<li class="menubar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Subscriber Mgmt">Subscriber Mgmt</a>
<ul>
<li>
<li>
<a href="/pmi/spcm-flow/customers/customers.html" title="Customers">Customers</a>

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='Customers']")).click();` instead of finding element with `linktext()` and provided some wait before clicking customers link if needed

Comment: still not working I cannot figure out why

Comment: Any Iframe on the page?

Comment: yes, what would be the impact of having Iframe when trying to locate the xpath? I thought the reason for using xpath is for problems that Iframe may create.

Comment: You need to set focus in IFrame before looking for element. do `driver.switchTo.frame("name or ondex of frame");` and then click customer link. You also need to switch back to default content to go back to default page content

Comment: the only use if iframe is here <iframe src="chrome-extension://hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl/bar.html" id="xh-bar" class="top" style="height: 0px; visibility: hidden;"/>. Would this effect my Webdriver script? I still cannot get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You were missing closing `}` and the selector for customers element may be the reason of failure as well

```
package firsttestngpackage;    

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestNGFile {
    public String baseUrl = "http://zzzz";
    public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @BeforeTest
    public void login() {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("z_username"));
        id.sendKeys("todd");
        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("z_password"));
        pass.sendKeys("todd");
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("login"));
        button.submit();
    }

    @Test
    public void createSub() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='Customers']")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void terminateBrowser() {
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```